# How to perform a Database API Inner query

Tags: 7, database

I have this Database API code, and I'm trying to add a sub-query to it:

```
$query = db_select('' . $base_table . '', 'n')
      ->extend('PagerDefault');
      ->extend('TableSort');
```

to turn this:

```
SELECT 
FROM 
taxonomy_term_data n
ORDER BY n.tid ASC
```

Into this:

```
SELECT 
FROM 
(SELECT * taxonomy_term_data LIMIT 10) n
ORDER BY n.tid ASC
```

I've tried passing a db_select statement into another db_select statement. I've tried query->addExpression() and db_query() to no avail.

Comment: Sometimes you just have to use `db_query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can refer to this [link](https://api.drupal.org/comment/17859#comment-17859)

However you can try like below

```
$query->condition('<condition>', $subquery);
```

Comment: yes that will work